# Menu dinâmico no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, menu

Estou tentando construir um menu dinâmico com submenus que insira links provenientes do banco de dados.
Eu escrevi o código abaixo diretamente em minha view para testar e funcionou perfeitamente:

```
<?php
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->where('category_id_parent', 0);
    $menu_list = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
        <li>
            <a href=""><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?></a>

            <?php

            $cat_id = $menu->category_id;

            $this->db->from('categories');
            $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
            $submenu_list = $this->db->get();

            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($submenu_list->result() as $submenu): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Então resolvi criar o model e o controller e adaptar a nova view.

O model ficou assim:

```
public function get_menu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent' => 0));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query;
    endif;
}

public function get_submenu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent' => 0));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    endforeach;
    if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

O controller :

```
public function menu() {
    $data['menu_list'] = $this->Menu_model->get_menu();
    $data['submenu_list'] = $this->Menu_model->get_submenu();
    $this->load->view('frontend/header', $data);
}
```

A view:

```
<?php foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#" ><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?> </a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($submenu_list->result() as $submenu): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Está quase tudo funcionando exceto os submenus que repetem os mesmos links.

Onde eu estou errando?

Eu refiz o método get_submenu apenas para pegar os ids do submenu:

```
public function get_submenu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent !=' => 0));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do jeito que está a estrutura do seus códigos, você tem que especificar qual menu pertence o submenu na View:

```
<?php foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
<li>
    <a href="#" ><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?> </a>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($submenu_list->result() as $submenu): ?>
            <?php if($menu->category_id==$submenu->category_id_parent):?>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português. De forma a tornar a sua resposta mais completa o código deveria ser acompanhado com uma pequena explicação.

Comment: Adicionado. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Na sua view, você deve buscar o submenu para cada menu... e configurar o método get_submenu para pegar apenas os submenus do menu em questão...

```
<?php foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
<li>
    <a href="#" ><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?> </a>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($menu->get_sumenu()->result() as $submenu): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Vagner, não funcionou.

Comment: poste o que aconteceu... e se aconteceu a mesma coisa, vc deve alterar seu método get_submenu para pegar os submenus da instancia atual (menu atual)

Comment: Olá Vagner, postagem em minha pergunta nas últimas linhas.